# how to use a Task.Run in a static method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to use a Task.Run in a static method. But when i m calling the task.run in static method it gets lost.

```
  public static void TestLevel()
   {
       var UserSetting = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            return await database.GetSettingByName("test");
        }).Result.Value;

        User objuser = new User();
        objuser.usersetting = UserSetting;
   }
```

When it is calling the task.run its not coming back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you're calling this from a UI or ASP.NET request thread. In that case, it is the `Result` that is causing a deadlock, as I explain [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

You should use `await` instead of `Result`:

```
public static async Task TestLevelAsync()
{
    var UserSetting = await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        return await database.GetSettingByName("test");
    });

    User objuser = new User();
    objuser.usersetting = UserSetting.Value;
}
```

Also, consider following the [Task-based asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx). In this case, you would rename `GetSettingByName` to `GetSettingByNameAsync` and move any `Task.Run` usage into that method.